# Transparent proxying - how to pass socket to local server without modification?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, proxy

I have a program that listens on port 443 and then redirects to either an SSH or HTTPS local server depending on the detected protocol.

The program does this by connecting to the local server and proxying all data back and forth through its own process.

However, this causes the originating host on the local servers to be logged as localhost.

Is there any way to pass the socket directly to the local server process (rather than just making a new TCP connection) so that the parameters of `sockaddr_in` (or `sockaddr_in6`) will be retained?

Platform for this is Linux.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a code snippet taken from [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/download/source.html) (from client.c in the local_bind function if you want to look at all the code).

```
#ifdef IP_TRANSPARENT
int on=1;
if(c->opt->option.transparent) {
    if(setsockopt(c->fd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &on, sizeof on))
        sockerror("setsockopt IP_TRANSPARENT");
    /* ignore the error to retain Linux 2.2 compatibility */
    /* the error will be handled by bind(), anyway */
}
#endif /* IP_TRANSPARENT */

memcpy(&addr, &c->bind_addr.addr[0], sizeof addr);
if(ntohs(addr.in.sin_port)>=1024) { /* security check */
    if(!bind(c->fd, &addr.sa, addr_len(addr))) {
        s_log(LOG_INFO, "local_bind succeeded on the original port");
        return; /* success */
    }
    if(get_last_socket_error()!=EADDRINUSE
#ifndef USE_WIN32
            || !c->opt->option.transparent
#endif /* USE_WIN32 */
            ) {
        sockerror("local_bind (original port)");
        longjmp(c->err, 1);
    }
}
```

Earlier, c->bind_addr was set to the address of the connecting peer with this code:

```
    else if(c->opt->option.transparent)
    memcpy(&c->bind_addr, &c->peer_addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_LIST));
```

The stunnel documentation contains this advice for recent Linux kernels:

> Remote mode (either 2.2.x and >=2.6.28) requires stunnel to be executed as root. setuid option will also break this functionality.
>
> Linux >=2.6.28 requires the following setup for iptables and routing (possibly in /etc/rc.local or equivalent file):

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! but unfortunately that technique does not appear to work when the destination host is localhost

Comment: @Luca Farber: I added some more information taken from the stunnel FAQ. Try that.

Comment: Hmm, despite fiddling around with it a lot, I can't seem to get it any further than connect(), where it hangs. "netstat -a -n" shows the connection in state of SYN_SENT (with remote host/port as source and 127.0.0.1:localport as destination).

Comment: See if you can get something like stunnel working. Maybe there's a trick your code is missing.

Comment: From stunnel manpage:
        -T  transparent proxy mode

           Re-write address to appear as if wrapped daemon is connecting from the SSL client machine instead of the machine running stunnel. Available only on some operating
           systems (Linux only, we believe) and then only in server mode. Note that this option will not combine with proxy mode (-r) unless the client's default route to the
           target machine lies through the host running stunnel, *which cannot be localhost*.

Answer (score 6):

If you have control over the local server processes, then you can do this.  Create a persistent UNIX-domain socket connection between the proxy process and the server process, then use `sendmsg()` on that UNIX-domain socket to pass a `SCM_RIGHTS` message containing the TCP socket's file descriptor.  The proxy process can then close its handle to the TCP socket.

When the server process gets passed a file descriptor from the proxy in a `SCM_RIGHTS` message, it just has to add it to its normal set of client sockets, as if it had come from `accept()`.

Comment: Thanks that is very interesting, though unfortunately I do not have control over the local servers; they are essentially black boxes

Answer (score 1):

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741535/388191, it is possible to do this with traffic to localhost by using connmark to keep track of the incoming local transparent connection and mark the outgoing packets to reroute them back to the local host:

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i lo -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 2 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```