# c- Loadbalancer.Modify http header when splicing?

Tags: c, sockets, http, http-headers, load-balancing

## UPDATE :

I edited my question to focus it more on the problem.

## Context

Coding to understand how loadbalancing works.
Debian 64 bits.

loadbalancer on 127.0.0.1:36001
backend on 127.0.0.1:36000

curl calling on loadbalancer (36001).

## Problem

I took this code to create my socket [socket code](https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/)

I created a very naive loadbalancer, a server and I have a curl request to the loadbalancer.
My problem is that I don't understand how to pass the client port/ip to the backend to anwser directly to curl when splicing.

## The code

#### curl request

curl localhost:36001 -d "salute"

#### loadbalancer

```
        static int pool_of_conn[2],
                   pool_of_pipes[2][2];
        int sentinel , efd;
        struct epoll_event event;
        struct epoll_event *events;
        ...

        off64_t offset = 0;

        pipe(pool_of_pipes[0]);
        
        /* This splice works but sends the loadbalancer ip and port. How to put the client's here ? How to alter events[i].data.fd ? */
        bytes = splice(events[i].data.fd, NULL, pool_of_pipes[0][1], NULL, 4096, SPLICE_F_MOVE);
        if (bytes == 0)
          break;
        splice(pool_of_pipes[0][0], NULL, pool_of_conn[0], NULL, bytes, SPLICE_F_MOVE);
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: I added a few HTTP related tags, so people who know more about HTTP might find this.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue with your problem is that HTTP, goes over TCP, which is a connection oriented protocol. So, even if you could make the connection to the backend appear to come from the client IP address, the TCP connection is established between the load balancer and backend. Thus the return TCP packets use that connection also. To somehow work around this, you would need for HTTP to use a different TCP connection for the request and reply and also manipulate local IP routing to behave so that the backends reply still goes to the actual client.

If your intent is to make a HTTP load balancer, the easiest solution probably lies somehwere on the application protocol (i.e. HTTP) level. You could use HTTP redirects or something more complex, like wrapping the client request in some headers before forwarding it. Im sure existing HTTP load balancers offer plenty of examples and ideas.

That said, if you want to solve this on the TCP connection level, transparently to the application protocols, it is doable, but it does require quite a bit of additional code. Also, the backends reply still goes through the load balancer. My suggestion would be to look into the IP option [IP_TRANSPARENT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html). It would allow your load balancer to use the clients IP address as source, when connecting to the backend. (Note that the return traffic also goes through the load balancer, so your `splice()` comes in handy)

Here is an old SO question about `IP_TRANSPARENT` [Transparent proxying - how to pass socket to local server without modification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741463/transparent-proxying-how-to-pass-socket-to-local-server-without-modification/2741535#2741535)

and here is the Linux kernel documentation for it https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt